# rails showing . instead of / in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a `static_controller` with `index` action where an id is needed

My routes

```
  get 'faqs' => 'static#main'
  get 'faqs/:id' => 'static#index'
```

but if I use this path `faqs_path(faq_id)` I get

`http://localhost:5000/faq.1` instead of `http://localhost:5000/faq/1`

Could someone tell me how to fix this. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to name them properly:

```
get 'faqs' => 'static#main', as: 'faqs'
get 'faqs/:id' => 'static#index', as: 'faq'
```

Normally you do this with `resources` where you try to adhere to REST conventions, but in your case if you really need them this way you'll have to coach the router.

Check with `rake routes` that the names are correct. You may have been calling `faqs_path` with the `id` going in as the optional `:format` specifier.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is same routes name, you can change your name as:

```
get 'faqs/:id' => 'static#index'
get 'faqs' => 'static#main'
```

to

```
get 'faq/:id' => 'static#index'
get 'faqs' => 'static#main'
```

And your `path` is: `faq_path(faq_id)`

Tell me if it didn't work.

Comment: @Abhilash i updated my answer, can you check it again ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try. `faqs_path(:id => faq_id)`

Comment: that will work but it will put the params in `?id=` instead of `/`

Comment: its a get request anyway..so params will be appended at the end.let me know if this answer helped :)

Comment: You have to change the routes then,as this is what you are asking to work..get 'faqs/:id' => 'static#index'